# Listing files from azure file storage that are 10 days old using shell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-files

```
$context=New-AzureStorageContext <AccountName> <AccountKey>
$isOldDate = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-10)
Get-AzureStorageFile -Context $context | Where-Object { 
    $_.LastModified.UtcDateTime -lt $isOldDate
}
```

The above code is listing all the files present in a fileshare instead of listing the files that are 10 days old. Need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$files = Get-AzureStorageFile -Context $context 
foreach ($file in $files) { $file.fetchattributesasync() }
$files.where{ $_.properties.lastmodified -le $date }
```

this is what works for me for files

Comment: No even this is listing all the files in that fileshare

Comment: well, what are you looking for exactly? older than 10 days or younger? maybe all files are older than 10 days?

Comment: Looking for the files that are older than 10. Not all files are older than 10. It shouldn't be listing all the files since I'm giving "-10".

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this, It is still listing me all the files. There are 5 files in my file share out of which 4 are 10 days old and 1 is a day old. The result for the code is for all 5 files.

Comment: just use 5 days, not 10

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: well, this is a working code, look for a typo in your code. another thing you might need to do is - get files, not directories, but seeing how you say it returns files, I assume you've done that